# Entity Framework Core create query using ifs

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Something like this:

```
        Itens = db.Transacao.AsNoTracking()
            if (x == 1)
                .Where(w => w.Confirmado == true)
            else
                .Where(w => w.Data.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
            .Include(i => i.Pessoa)
            .Include(i => i.Categoria)
            .ToList();
```

I know that this don't exist, but, exist something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
IQueryable<[your entity here]> query = db.Transacao.AsNoTracking();
if (x == 1)
    query = query.Where(w => w.Confirmado == true);
else
    query = query.Where(w => w.Data.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date);

return query.Include(i => i.Pessoa)
            .Include(i => i.Categoria)
            .ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When it is a table with few records I use this.

But when there is a lot of records in the table we have problems.

`IQueryable<[your entity here]> query = db.Transacao.AsNoTracking();`


Here we get all the records, and only after we filter they.

If we could create the query first, and only in the end we Apply the query.

Comment: The query doesn't get executed until you call the .ToList() method, so you're not getting any records on the AsNoTracking() line, you're just building the query. Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works

Comment: It is true. you are right. I got confused because in debugger if you watch the variable then the records came, but only because I watched that.. This solution will solve my problem. thankyou